# Hackerrank Repeated String infinite loop problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup) hackerrank problem for counting the number of `'a'`s in a given string.

My solution was to store the string in a `pattern` variable. While the length of the `pattern` is less than `n`, it will just add the string to itself. Then I would loop over the `pattern` and add the number of `'a'`s in the string.

This solution works fine when `n` < `1000000`. But add one more 0 and when `n` = `10000000`, I get a `RangeError` for my string in hackerrank because it's too damn long.

Is there a way to get around this `RangeError` problem? I know there are other ways to solve this problem, but I just want to know how I could edit my code to make it pass the hackerrank test.

```
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let pattern = s;
  let count = 0;
  while (pattern.length < n) {
    pattern += pattern;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (pattern[i] === 'a') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Building the string itself and then looping over it isn't very efficient. JS has an upper limit on the size that a string can be which you're exceeding. You'll need to change your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do math on this rather than consume the memory and calculation on string concatenation and loop

The total number of `a` would be the number of `a` in `s` times the repeated number of `s` that has total length not exceed `n`, plus the remainder (left substring) of `s` that fill the `n`

For example, with the input

```
s = 'aba'
n = 10
```

It could be simply visually in the below

```
 aba  aba  aba   a(ba)
|______3______| |1|
```

First 3 repeated of `aba` equals `n` divided by length of `s` (i.e 10 / 3 = 3)

The leftover `a` (skips `bc` to equals with `n`) is the result of `s` sliced with the length equals remainder of `n` divided by length of `s` (i.e 10 % 3 = 1)

Plus two of these then we get the result

```
numberOfA(s) * (n div len(s)) + numberOfA(substr(s, 0, n mod len(s)))
```

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  const numberOfA = str => str.split('').filter(char => char === 'a').length
  return (
    numberOfA(s) * Math.floor(n / s.length) +
    numberOfA(s.substring(0, n % s.length))
  )
}

console.log(repeatedString('aba', 10))
console.log(repeatedString('a', 1000000000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

php solution for repeated String

```
    function repeatedString($s, $n) {
       $len = strlen($s);
       $occurence = substr_count($s, "a");
       $mul = floor ($n / $len);
       $reminder = $n % $len;
       $su = substr($s,0,$reminder);
       return ($occurence * $mul) + substr_count($su,"a");
    }
```